# Coding contour integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

I am struggling to understand contour integration. How would it be applied in *Mathematica*? I am hoping that if I see it written in *Mathematica* code, it will help me understand it. eg how would $$\int_\gamma \text{}(z) = \int_a^b \text{f}(z(t)) z'(t) \, \text{d}t$$ be coded? (Example taken form [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_contour_integration).)

Comment: It's basically a line integral of a scalar function of two variables along a path, $\gamma$ in your case. Do you not understand what it is conceptually or practically?

Comment: Conceptually, I'm afraid. I looked at [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34073/how-to-calculate-contour-integrals-with-mathematica) but I don't really understand it.

Comment: Is my first stop [MSE](http://math.stackexchange.com/)? (I was rather hoping not - I think it may be easier to pick apart if I see the coding.)

Comment: Hmm, I wish I had some time to explain it (it's probably easy once you get it). How about the first figure/animation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral), ie, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Line_integral_of_scalar_field.gif)? Any clearer what is going on?

Comment: OK, so it is the absolute area under a line in a 3-dimensional field?

Comment: I just don't get the whole "converging in disc $x$" business.

Comment: @martin so this is rather math.SE quesion, isn't it?

Comment: Yes - I think you are probably right - will come back here once I understand a little more ...

Comment: I just saw (after closing) that you're already aware of the contour integral question (which has a very good answer by Artes). From the rest of the comments, it seems like your question/confusion is more conceptual and I suggest asking it at [math.se], where you might get an indepth/layman explanation.

Comment: OK, thank you.,