# Drawing contour integral diagrams

Tags: graphics, calculus-and-analysis, complex

I am $\TeX$ writing notes on complex analysis, I need to use figures of contour paths to integrate on them, how can I plot them on *Mathematica*, something like this

[image: some contours]

adding also the $\gamma_R$ legends in $\TeX$ if possible ?

Comment: `Arrow[]` and `JoinedCurve[]` will be quite helpful here.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Thanks a lot, could you provide an example?, I am new to mathematica, even a simple one, like the first contour.

Comment: You might want to see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34073).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Preliminaries:

```
lin[x_] := {Arrowheads[{{0.05, 0.5}}], Arrow[Most@x]};
arc[x_] :=
  {Arrowheads[{{0.05, 0.5}}], 
   Arrow[Table[
     x[[1]] {Cos[j], x[[-2]] Sin[j]}, {j, x[[2]], x[[3]], 
      0.01 (x[[3]] - x[[2]])}]]};
cont[lst_] := If[#[[-1]] == "line", lin@#, arc@#] & /@ lst
```

Example of right most contour but you could adapt to others by specifying contour as list of elements (am time poor at present):

```
 im[d_, o_] := 
     Graphics[{Red, 
       cont[{{{o, d}, {1, d}, "line"}, {1, ArcTan[d], 2 Pi - ArcTan[d], 1,
           "arc"}, {{1, -d}, {o, -d}, "line"}, {Norm[{o, d}], ArcTan[d/o],
           2 Pi - ArcTan[d/o], -1, "arc"}}], Black, 
       Text["|z|=1/R", 2 Norm[{o, d}] {Cos[3 Pi/4], Sin[3 Pi/4]}]}, 
      Axes -> True, 
      Ticks -> {{{1.1, "R"}, {-1.1, "-R"}}, {{1.1, "i R"}, {-1.1, 
          "-i R"}}}, PlotRange -> {{-1.3, 1.3}, {-1.3, 1.3}}]
```

You can format text and contour as desired.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Loved the .gif !!

Comment: What? No $\eta_R$?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork yes I apologise for the omission for the labeling of the contour as well as the failure to suppress the tick mark (as you did with 0 option in tick specification). My principal aim was to start to generalize and illustrate with contour that was most "interesting"...done at midnight after 14 hour day...so not firing on all cylinders

Answer (score 5):

```
Graphics[
   {Text[Style["|z| = 1/R", 22, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"], {-.4, .15}],
    Text[Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Eta]\), \(R\)]\)", 22, Italic, 
    FontFamily -> "Times"], {.8, .8}],
  {Red, 
   {Arrowheads[.05], Arrow[{{.01, 1}, {-.01, 1}}]}, 
   {Arrowheads[.05], Arrow[{{-.01, -1}, {.01, -1}}]},
   {Arrowheads[.05], Arrow[{{.15, .05}, {.6, .05}}]},
   {Arrowheads[.05], Arrow[{{1, -.05}, {.4, -.05}}]},
   Line[{{.6, .05}, {1, .05}}],
   Line[{{.4, -.05}, {.15, -.05}}],
   Circle[{0, 0}, .15, {.3, 2 \[Pi] - .3}],
   Circle[{0, 0}, 1, {.05, 2 \[Pi] - .05}]}},
 Axes -> True, 
 Ticks -> {{{1.1, Text[Style["R", Italic, 24]], 0}, 
           {-1.1, Text[Style["-R", Italic, 24]], 0}}, 
          {{ 1.1, Text[Style["iR", Italic, 24]], 0}, 
           {-1.1, Text[Style["-iR", Italic, 24]], 0}}},
 PlotRange -> {{-1.2, 1.2}, {-1.2, 1.2}}]
```

[image]