# Residue theorem and multiple poles in contour integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I had a query on multiples poles in [*Contour Integral*][1] using the  [*Residue Theorem*][2]. I had an integral which I wanted to solve using the *Residue Theorem*. By the help of mathematica experts i solved my problem.

```
       Δ = .3;
       λ = .1;
       b =  .1;
       a1 = λ^2 + Δ^2 - b^2;
       a2 = 2*Δ*λ;

       den[z_] := z (z^4*a2 - z^2*I*2*a1 - a2)
       num[y_] := I*(y^2 (Δ - I*λ) - (Δ + I*λ))^2
       poles = z /. Solve[den[z] == 0, z];
       fun[z_] := (1/a2) num[z]/(Times @@ (z - poles))
       cand = {#, Residue[fun[z], {z, #}]} & /@ poles;
       Total@Cases[cand, {_?(Abs@# < 1 &), y_} :> y] // Timing
```

And the output is

```
       {0., 1.14907 - 1.11022*10^-16 I}
```

By using Principlevalue command output is same but

```
       D1 = 1/\[Pi] Integrate[(Δ*Sin[z] - λ*Cos[z])^2/(
       a1 - a2*Sin[2*z]), {z, 0, 2*\[Pi]}, PrincipalValue -> True] // 
       Timing
```

And the out put is
           {1.016, 1.14907 + 0. I}
 Both are same but Residue sum method takes smaller time. Thanks to everyone for helping me in solving this problem.

Comment: Unfortunately no. By using calculator i found net  sum of residues {-0.0399975 - 0.0849706 I, 0.0229189 - 0.0305566 I, 0.0233393 + 0.0495896 I}. And sum of all these resiudes is 0.917871 + 0.0366954 I.

Answer (score 3):

The `Residue` can be zero at a pole ([look here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexResidue.html)). For example $1/z^2$ has a residue 0 at z=0. If you make a [Laurent Series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LaurentSeries.html) there will no term with `1/z`. (It depends on the analyticity of the function at the pole). For your function you can verify it easily by following b.gatessucks 's suggestion.

```
f = NPI11[z]/D1;
Normal[Series[NPI11[z]/D1, {z, #, 1}]] & /@ dM
```

and you will see for only `z0=0` the series has a term with `1/z` and hence the `Residue` gives you zero for other poles.

For verifying your result you can also check [How to calculate contour integrals with Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34073/how-to-calculate-contour-integrals-with-mathematica) .

> Another example

Another example you can check is `Sin[x]/x` which has one pole at `z=0` and `0` residue.

```
Residue[Sin[z]/z, {z, 0}]
```

Comment: ,But my function dont have any second order pole because all of the poles are distinct. There is no 1/z^2 comparison possible here.

Comment: Is there any command in mathematica which can replace the list of poles which are solution of denominator to (z-z1)(z-z2)(z-z3)..(z-zn) form. I think then it may work.

Comment: you can look for `TransferFunctionPoles` or may be simply `Factor[D1]`.

Answer (score 1):

Some definitions:

```
subs = {\[CapitalDelta] -> .3, \[Lambda] -> .1, 
   a1 -> 0.090001` - 0.0002` I, a2 -> 0.06`};
num = -(z^2 (\[CapitalDelta] - I*\[Lambda]) - (\[CapitalDelta] + 
        I*\[Lambda]))^2 ;
den = z (z^4*a2 - z^2*I*2*a1 - a2);
poles = Solve[den == 0, z]
```

This gives a list with the pairs `pole, residue` analytically:

```
polres = Map[{#[[1, 2]], Residue[num/den, {z, #[[1, 2]]}]} &, poles]
```

Now we can get the numeric value corresponding to your parameters:

```
polres /. subs
(*
{{0, 1.33333 + 1. I}, 
 {-0.43636 - 0.437662 I, -0.668455 + 0.0745192 I}, 
 {0.43636 + 0.437662 I, -0.668455 + 0.0745192 I}, 
 {-1.14584 - 1.14243 I, -0.664878 - 0.0745192 I}, 
 {1.14584 + 1.14243 I, -0.664878 - 0.0745192 I}}
*)
```

However if we calculate the residues on the numerical values:

```
Map[{#[[1, 2]], Residue[num/den, {z, #[[1, 2]]}]} &, poles /. subs]
(*
{{0, (\[CapitalDelta]^2 + 2 I \[CapitalDelta] \[Lambda] - \[Lambda]^2)/a2}, 
 {-0.43636 - 0.437662 I, 0}, 
 {0.43636 + 0.437662 I, 0}, 
 {-1.14584 - 1.14243 I, 0}, 
 {1.14584 + 1.14243 I, 0}}
*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the specified values and defining numerator and denominator

```
den[z_] := z (z^4*a2 - z^2*I*2*a1 - a2)   
num[y_] := -(y^2 (\[CapitalDelta] - I*\[Lambda]) - (\[CapitalDelta] + 
       I*\[Lambda]))^2
```

As you are dealing with polynomials you can just use the polynomial roots and make life easier for `Residue`:

```
roots = z /. Solve[num[z] == 0, z];
poles = z /. Solve[den[z] == 0, z];
fun[z_] := (-(\[CapitalDelta] - I*\[Lambda])^2/
a2) Times @@ (z - roots)/(Times @@ (z - poles))
```

then the contour integral (unit circle):

```
cand = {#, Residue[fun[z], {z, #}]} & /@ poles;
2 Pi I Total@ Cases[cand, {_?(Abs@# < 1 &), y_} :> y]
```

yielding: -7.21962 - 0.022478 I

The poles and residues

```
TableForm[
 cand /. {{x_?(Abs@# < 1 &), y_} :> {Style[x, Red], Style[y, Red]}}, 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"Pole", "Residue"}}]
```

yields:

[image]

Note: the leading coefficientis taken into account in redefinition: `fun[z]`

Comment: When i integrate the function by using principaleValue then i got a different answer. Which is correct answer.D1 = 1/\[Pi] Integrate[(\[CapitalDelta]*Sin[z] - \[Lambda]*Cos[z])^2/(
   a1 - a2*Sin[2*z]), {z, 0, 2*\[Pi]}, PrincipalValue -> True]  out put is 1.14907 + 0. I. That is correct value. But my task is to find this value by residue theorem. I have tried a lot, that's why i asked here.

Comment: @HazoorImran I am sorry I am unsure what your aim is. Perhaps you could edit your question with the integral you are trying to evaluate and the contour...

Comment: @UPDQN I was trying to solve trignometric function integral by using residue theorem. The results were not matching from the two different methods (PrincipalValue and residue theorm). But now i am happy because finally by the help of you and other experts supports i solved this problem.