# Contour Integration in Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I need to solve an integral similar to following for a project:

\begin{equation}
 F[p^2\_,q^2\_]\equiv\int_0^{\infty}dk\, e^{-k/\lambda}\, \frac{k}{k-b[p^2,q^2]- I\epsilon}\ln(k-b[p^2,q^2])
\end{equation}

Here, $\lambda$ is a real number, while $b$ is a function of $p^2$ and $q^2$ which are invariant masses.

If I run it without the logarithmic function, Mathematica computes it. However, it is not giving any answer for the above integral. How do I solve it in Mathematica? Is there any other software which I can use to do solve it?

Comment: This question is *much* more suited to the [Mathematica.SE] site.

Comment: I agree it is suited to the Mathematica SE, however integrals of this type are a speciality for high energy theorists so they may offer some insight.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question belongs to MathematicaSE.

Comment: Does this answer your question [How to calculate contour integrals with Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34073/how-to-calculate-contour-integrals-with-mathematica/34090#34090)