# How to plot symbolic curves/contours in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting, graphics, complex

I want to plot a contour for a complex integral such as the one shown below:

[image]

Is it possible to do this in Mathematica using `Graphics`

Comment: Yes, it is possible!

Comment: This has more elaborate examples of contours: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34073/how-to-calculate-contour-integrals-with-mathematica

Comment: Start with basics first:  Lines, points, circles, arrows, the `Text` command,  the help files.  First type "Circle" in a notebook, hover over it, choose the "i" for information or select from the drop down menu.  Work the examples.  Do the same for the others.   Then I'm sure you can generate that plot above.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways of doing this sort of thing.

You might start with something like

```
Region[RegionBoundary[
          RegionDifference[
             RegionIntersection[Disk[{0, 0}], 
             HalfPlane[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}, {0, 1}]], 
             RegionUnion[Disk[{-1/2, 0}, 1/10], Disk[{1/2, 0}, 1/10]]]]]
```

[image: Contour]